# Knockoutjs - .sort() sorting in reverse order in Safari

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, safari

In my Knockout view model I have the following:

```
this.Files.sort(function(f1, f2) {
    if (mostRecentFirst) {
        return f1.CreationDate < f2.CreationDate ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return f1.CreationDate > f2.CreationDate ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

In Firefox, Chrome and IE this sorts as expected.

But in Safari it sorts in the reverse order.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

**UPDATE:** the CreationDate property contains a JSON date string, *eg* "2013-04-26T12:08:02".

**UPDATE 2:** I've actually got around this problem by using push or unshift to add elements to the array, but this isn't a great solution because it assumes that the data which is presented has already been ordered. So it's no longer an immediate problem but I'd still like to know why Safari was sorting in the reverse order.

Comment: What data type is `CreationDate`?

Comment: I've updated to show the data type.

Comment: Which safari version? Are you sure that the `mostRecentFirst` is always the same during your tests?

Comment: Yes, mostRecentFirst is actually hard-coded in the JS. And it's the latest version of Safari.